# How to display Magnifying glass of IOS when pangesture or tapgesture

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, loupe

I want to display magnifying glass of iOS 7 when I tap gesture with `UITextView`.

Please help me!!!!

Comment: There is one lib on github https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass

Answer (score 0):

please check below link.all lib's are related to Magnifying glass sample app

https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=magnifying+glass&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 0):

add this code in .m file where you have called subclass UITextfield

```
   -(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
  {
    //Prevent zooming but not panning
     if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) 
        {
              gestureRecognizer.enabled =YES;
        }
       [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
        return;
   }
```